# How to instal polyglot on mac?

Tags: python

When following the [instructions](http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html) I get the following error message:

```
Failed building wheel for PyICU
```

One of the dependencies is missing. However the module `PyICU` cannot be installed with homebrew (i.e. `brew install PyICU`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `icu4c` instead of `PyICU`.

Follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352241/1053612
(May require installing python between steps 1 and 2, i.e. `brew install python`).

Answer (score 1):

Go in you working folder

`cd ~/projects/pythontest`

## initialize python and the environment

`brew install python3.7`

`pip3 install virtualenv`

`virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 python_env`

## install all polyglot dependencies

`brew install intltool icu4c gettext`

`brew link icu4c gettext --force`

create shorcut for pip3, python3 and polyglot as we will use them a lot

`pip3=./python_env/bin/pip3; polyglot=./python_env/bin/polyglot;python3=./python_env/bin/python3;`

if you have already installed pyicu it is important to delete it

`$pip3 uninstall pyicu`

Install pyicu and replace with the good version

`ICU_VERSION=64.2 CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib $pip3 install pyicu`

`$pip3 install pycld2 morfessor six numpy polyglot`

## test it

create a file`polytest.py`

```
from polyglot.text import Text

blob = u"""
世界就是一个疯子的囚笼
"""
text = Text(blob)
print(text.words)
```

And run the file
`$python3 polytest.py`

Answer (score 1):

If your ICU version is >= 60.

To successfully install PyICU (polyglot dependency), follow the instructions from bonna's answer and set the PYICU_CFLAGS environment variable required by the C++ compiler.

```
export PYICU_CFLAGS=-std=c++11:-DPYICU_VER='"2.0.3"'
```

See [Unable to install pyicu on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203597/unable-to-install-pyicu-on-macos)