# Unable to install pyicu on MacOS

Tags: python, pyicu

I tried installing through `pip3 install pyicu` and got following error:

```
Collecting pyicu
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/ef/3a7fcbba81bfd213e479131ae21445a2ddd14b46d70ef0109640b580bc5d/PyICU-2.0.3.tar.gz

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Building PyICU 2.0.3 for ICU 61

Could not configure CXXFLAGS with icu-config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/80/v1nwf70x2rz5srmzfnpc3pq40000gn/T/pip-build-b_sify1x/pyicu/setup.py", line 131, in <module>
    _cflags, ('--cxxflags', '--cppflags'), 'CXXFLAGS')
  File "/private/var/folders/80/v1nwf70x2rz5srmzfnpc3pq40000gn/T/pip-build-b_sify1x/pyicu/setup.py", line 30, in configure_with_icu_config
    output = check_output(('icu-config',) + config_args).strip()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icu-config'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/80/v1nwf70x2rz5srmzfnpc3pq40000gn/T/pip-build-b_sify1x/pyicu/
```

Then from some source I got to know that I need to install `icu4c` and configure by `.bash_profile` for icu. Also tried doing that but error persists. Please help me out.

Comment: Try running this in the command line: 

export PYICU_CFLAGS=-std=c++11:-DPYICU_VER='"2.0.3"'

Comment: It worked atlast. searched whole internet and was unable to do it, but you solved it with one line command. Great! Thanks @Bilzard

Comment: Please, set my answer as the accepted answer so other people know the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running this in the command line:

```sh
export PYICU_CFLAGS=-std=c++11:-DPYICU_VER='"2.0.3"'
```