# unable to run Morphological Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x

my program is applying Morphological Analysis called polyglot on Arabic words.
but when i run the program this error comes up:

```
 ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_icu.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libicui18n.54.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_icu.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

this is a part of my code:

```
  from polyglot.downloader import downloader
  from polyglot.text import Text, Word


   #function for PreProcessing:
   def PreProcess_text(Input):
        tokens=regexp_tokenize(Input, r'[،؟!.؛\s+]\s*', gaps=True)
        Free= Remove_StopWords(normlization(tokens))
        correct= Autocorrect(Free)
        morph= Morphing(correct)
        #tag= tagging(correct)
        return morph 


   H = input('H:')
   Cleand= PreProcess_text(H)
   print(Cleand)
```

i'm using Python3 on Mac Serria OS.

thank you,

Comment: You are missing `libicu-dev`. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33352241/448496).

Comment: @rubik thank you, but i've tried his solution and the same error came up.