# install pyicu on mac; library not found for -licule

Tags: python, macos, pyicu

I having some difficulties to install pyicu in my mac. I first had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259191/installing-libicu-dev-on-mac) problem, that is I solved. But now the instalation is giving the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -licule
```

So, which library is this licule?

Answer (score 3):

pyicu 58.1 is just released in homebrew and it lacks libicule, pip needs libicule to compile pyicu. Till this problem is fixed you can downgrade to pyicu 57.1. To do so you can do this:

```
brew remove icu4c
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git checkout 1e62c645b2fc2d82042d9f7c364c6a246f2e11ed Formula/icu4c.rb #this is the latest commit with 57.1 I guess based on git log.
brew install icu4c
brew link --force icu4c
```

and then

```
pip install pyicu
```

I didn't try above myself but should work, let me know if it didn't and I'll try to make sure it runs on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already had the same (correct) answer in [https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu/issues/34]. It's working now.